# Obtaining root access

Tags: root-access

I have a LGMS500 (never again), I have used Link2SD and Advanced SD Card manager and have moved as many apps as I can to SD card and this was not many. Any other app I try to move to SD card I receive the following "Could not obtain root access" "Allow or Grant to superuser". OK, newbe here when it comes to android, how do I obtain root access? While understanding this term as a former programmer, I have absolutely no glimmer on how to do this with Android.

Answer (score 0):

It is slightly different for every device, I'd recommend seeing if there are any threads specific to your device and how to root it  at forum.xda-developers.com be careful to follow all steps correctly to avoid bricking your device.

Comment: *how do I obtain root access?* -- This is clearly mentioned and is still unanswered in what you posted as an answer. I recommend to please look for a clear-cut solution and post it here. Otherwise, if you have a recommendation as a clue or a hint (XDA here), do post it as a comment and not as answer. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have enough reputation to comment. But I'll get a direct link to an XDA thread on how to root this specific device.

Comment: Sure :) and please quote/edit the content of XDA thread(if you get it) here so that if that thread goes down for some reason in future, your answer will still be relevant to a reader.

Answer (score 0):

For an older version (<=4.3) try towelroot ( towelroot.com ) press logo get an apk, it's safe to use, so don't worry if your browser tells you it's malicious.

If it fails, look for other method for your phone model. There are thousands of manuals for that already.